# Survival analysis for predictive maintenance on one machine

Tags: machine-learning, python, survival

I have date for failures on one engine, 10 failures in total over a several years period, does it makes sense to split the data at each failure event and use the data with 10 failures as if I have ten engines with 1 failure each? For this case I'm can not get more data.

Answer (score 1):

That might make sense if you thought that the events all were independent, with the same risk over time. Even then, you would probably be better off using the data to fit an exponential survival model, which holds under those assumptions, to get an estimate of the hazard rate.

What probably makes most sense is to consider this as a recurrent event and to plot the *cumulative* events over time: with time on the x-axis, increase the event count (on the y-axis) by 1 at each event time. In principle, you might see acceleration or deceleration of the apparent event rate over time from such a curve, although with only 10 events that might be hard to evaluate.